# mysqli function returning no value

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

ok i have a mysqli function that draws a users stat from a database.  the datbase is set up as

username   attack   defense   strength
xxxx         10       10         10

the problem i am running into is the function is returning nothing, the page is blank. my connection to the database present and session username is stored so i can figure out why its not working.

config.php

```
 <?php
 $dbhost = 'xxx'; 
 $dbuser = 'xxx';
 $dbpass = 'xxx';
 $dbname = 'xxx';
 $dberror1 = 'could not connect to database';
 $dberror2 = 'could not find selected table';
 ?>
```

stat.php

```
<?php
function getLevel($stat) {
require_once 'includes/config.php';

$mysqli = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT ? FROM players WHERE username = ?");

if($stmt) {
 $stmt->bind_param('ss', $stat, $_SESSION['username']);
 if($stmt->execute()) {
      $stmt->bind_result($result);
      $stmt->fetch();
       }
  }
  return $result;
  }  

?>
```

and the file im using to test displaying the function

```
<?php
include 'includes/login-check.php';
include 'includes/config.php';
include 'includes/stat.php';

echo getLevel('attack');
?>
```

Comment: Have you checked for errors with mysqli_error($mysqli)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot bind table- or column names in your prepared statement, just values.

You would have to check the `$stat` value against a white-list and insert it directly in the sql statement.

By the way, you can tell `mysqli` to throw exceptions so that you don't have to check the return value of every database call manually. Just add this before you open your database connection:

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
```

Comment: an explnation on how to do this would be nice im new to mysqli i jsut converted this from mysql

Comment: @user3078244 Your sql would simply be `"SELECT \`$stat\` FROM players WHERE username = ?"` but you would have to make sure that `$stat` is safe to use, for example by checking it against a white-list of allowed column names.

Comment: i will have to look into this white-list thing but thanks for the information

Comment: @user3078244 The white-list is to avoid sql injection problems. Just generate an array with all allowed values and check if `$stat` exists in the array. If not, show an error message.

Comment: place the array within the function executed?

Comment: @user3078244 It has to be available in the function, so you have to define it there or pass it as a parameter. I would not open the db connection in the function myself, but open one global connection that I would pass around and I would probably do the same with the white-list. Then the db connection file would be a good place to define it. Or a settings / config file.